# I want to apply an external js file that will autohide my navigation bar

Tags: javascript, html

I want to apply a js I found here on stackoverflow to my navigation bar. This is aimed to autohide it after a moment of inactivity. But I dont know how to include and apply the code to my navigation bar.
This is how my html goes

```
    <div class="basic-wrapper"> 

        <a class="btn responsive-menu pull-right" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <i class='icon-menu-1'></i>
        </a> 

        <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>">
            <?php 
                if( get_option('custom_logo') ){
                    echo '<img src="'. get_option('custom_logo') .'" alt="" data-src="'. get_option('custom_logo') .'" data-ret="'. get_option('custom_logo_retina') .'" class="retina" />';
                } else {
                    echo bloginfo('title');
                    echo '<br /><small>';
                    echo bloginfo('description');
                    echo '</small>';
                }
            ?>
        </a> 

    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse pull-right">

        <?php
            if ( has_nav_menu( 'primary' ) ){
                wp_nav_menu( 
                    array(
                        'theme_location'    => 'primary',
                        'depth'             => 3,
                        'container'         => false,
                        'container_class'   => false,
                        'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav',
                        'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
                        'menu_id'           => 'ebor-main-menu',
                        'walker'            => new ebor_bootstrap_navwalker()
                    )
                );

            } else {
                echo '<a href="'. admin_url('nav-menus.php') .'">Set up a navigation menu now</a>';
            }

            if( get_option("header_social_link_1") )
                get_template_part('loop/loop','socialheader');
        ?>

    </div>

  </div><!--/.container-->
</div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
```

This is the code I found-

```
$("div").hide();

$("html").mousemove(function( event ) {
$("div").show();

myStopFunction();
myFunction();
});

function myFunction() {
myVar = setTimeout(function(){
    $("div").hide();
}, 1000);
}
function myStopFunction() {
if(typeof myVar != 'undefined'){
    clearTimeout(myVar);
}
}
```

Comment: @MohitBhasi brilliant advice thank you, however at this point it will be counter-productive for me to learn code. Did you have an answer anyway?

Answer (score 0):

If you are asign how to include an external javascript file, you need to do the following:

```
<script src="//path/to/external/js/file.js"></script>
```

As for the actual JS code, i dont think that will give you what you are looking for, as it will hide ALL DIVs on the page.

You'd want to replace that with something like. $("div#IDofMenuContatiner")...

Comment: Thank you, so I should replace all the "div" with the container ID. I am confused what the "html" is.

Comment: Yes, so it would look liek this:
$("div#someID")...
<div id='someID'></div>